# Q return a resolved promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am glancing over some example code that uses `promise` npm module and returns a resolved promise like so `return promise.resolve(true);`.

Since we use Q, is it possible to do the same with Q?

Comment: @Amit *nods* I did read the docs here https://www.npmjs.com/package/q still couldnt figure out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the solution your looking for is

```
> q(true).then(console.log.bind(console));
> true
```

Comment: Better than mine :-)

Comment: So, it'll be `Q(some value to return).then(function(){  })` right?

Comment: Again, see the [docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#q-object)

Comment: If value is not a promise, returns a promise that is fulfilled with value.